# Why does a global static variable take precedence over an extern within a function?

Tags: c, static, extern

this is hard to explain in text, so I will give an example.

```
//f1.c
int a = 5;

int main()
{
    printf("func2() output is: %i\n", func2() );
    return 0;
}


//f2.c
static int a = 3

int func2()
{
    extern int a;
    return a;
}
```

When I compile and run this, I get 3, while I was expecting 5. Can anyone explain to me why I get 3? I would have thought that by using extern within the function, it wouldn't use the value of the static variable.

Comment: Well, because that's how the standard defines it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From n1256 §6.2.2 ¶4:

> For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier `extern` in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible, if the prior declaration specifies internal or external linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration. If no prior declaration is visible, or if the prior declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external linkage.

So, `extern` within function scope means that the variable has external linkage by *default,* but if there's another visible definition, that definition is used instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `static` class-modifier denotes that the variable will only be visible in this translation-unit (`f2.c`) By using `extern` for `a`, you only declared that variable, but not defined it. Yet, there was an `a` available in the translation-unit `f2.c`, so this one will be used.